# C - Problem when I try to copy a struct from an array to an array contained in a struct

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, struct

Ok so I've two structures (player and team) that are respectively in the type of

```
typedef struct{
    int matricola_squadra;
    int matricola_giocatore;
    char cognome[20];
    char nome[20];
    char ruolo[4];
    bool attivo;
}calciatore;

typedef struct{
    int matricola;
    char nome_squadra[30];
    calciatore giocatori_squadra[MAX_GIOCATORI];
    int punti;
    int vittorie;
    int sconfitte;
    bool turno_di_pausa;
}squadra;
```

You can easily see that the 3rd element of the struct 'squadra' is an array of 'calciatori' (MAX_GIOCATORI = 20);

I put 20 'squadra' (team) in an array and 400 player (20 x team) in another, each of the type of the respective structure, in this way:

```
squadre_in_array(file_squadre, array_squadre, numero_squadre);
calciatori_in_array(file_calciatori, array_calciatori, numero_calciatori);
```

'**array_squadre**' and '**array_calciatori**' are full of square and calciatori and when I try to print them everything goes in the right way. The 'matricola' of **squadra** and 'matricola_squadra' of **calciatore** contains an id (equal for each 20 players but contained only one time in the teams) that I want to use to match them and move the 20 players that pass the match in the array of struct contained in the struct squadra. It's coming...

This is my function:

```
void calciatori_in_squadra(calciatore arcalc[], int maxcalcsqua, squadra arsqua[], int nsqua){
    for (int i = 0; i < nsqua; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < maxcalcsqua*nsqua; j++){
            if (arsqua[i].matricola == arcalc[j].matricola_squadra ){
                arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[j].matricola_squadra = arcalc[j].matricola_squadra;
                arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[j].matricola_giocatore = arcalc[j].matricola_giocatore;
                strcpy(arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[j].nome, arcalc[j].nome);
                strcpy(arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[j].cognome, arcalc[j].cognome);
                printf("Squadra: %20s - Nome: %20s\n", arsqua[i].nome_squadra, arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[j].nome);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

nsqua is the number of squadre (20) and maxcalcsqua is the maximum number of players in a team.
In this line I do my comparison and if the id of squadra (matricola) and the id of calciatore (matricola_squadra) match it does the copy.

The problem arrives on my 4th iteration when my program (i saw it with debug) transforms an id into another random number (idk why) and sometimes it changes the name of a 'squadra' when no manipulation is done on it... I'm going crazy

The id are of the type:

```
234859;Casper Team
234860;Logic Nation
234861;Boolean Choose
234862;FC Integer
234863;Majin Boo
234864;Vedinet Master
...
```

for the team and

```
234859;1;adaffwf;sgrwgwe;POR
234859;2;uyftfdgou;agsrgr;POR
234859;3;jfkdjgvfjd;greghhjejt;POR
234859;4;gfkjdzi;rgeg;DIF
234859;5;jgfidjzgop;agrrge;DIF
234859;6;jgfodpzj;gegrea;DIF
234859;7;jippp;aagrger;DIF
234859;8;nnndjhs;jkuyk;DIF
234859;9;qefsev;uykjr;DIF
234859;10;astgegbf;jkuyk;CEN
234859;11;befis;therg;CEN
234859;12;trisfbhs;erghejt;CEN
234859;13;gruidshfi;rjkw;CEN
234859;14;dnjsfhsj;hbe;CEN
234859;15;loejskfpo;behwjh;CEN
234859;16;jzshxd;wrtj;ATT
234859;17;ahiuoho;rtj;ATT
234859;18;pikop;rjtwrtjrtj;ATT
234859;19;huohdso;rwj;ATT
234859;20;opasidp;rjtjrtj;ATT
234860;21;akjdsopfksdop;qerbvrg;POR
234860;22;fsdopf;rjn;POR
234860;23;dsofdso;k;POR
234860;24;fdosf;ku;DIF
... (20 with the same team id to do the match correctly)
```

for the player

for example, my program put 197162 in the .matricola of the team with 234862 as id...
I know that it is a lot of code and I'm sure that the problem is in the function, the rest of the program runs well and I did my check... maybe it's a memory problem but I'm not sure.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If `j` goes up to `maxcalcsqua*nsqua-1`, it seems likely that `j>=MAX_GIOCATORI`, which would mean `arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[j]` isn't good.

Comment: Why are you multiplying `maxcalcsqua*nsqua`?

Comment: Because i`ve 20 players for team and 20 teams, so i use the j until 400 (the full list of player) to check if there are some match in all the list

Answer (score 0):

Ok i easily resolved my problem using this simple code, the problem was in the j iterator..

```
void calciatori_in_squadra(calciatore arcalc[], int maxcalcsqua, squadra arsqua[], int nsqua){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < nsqua; i++){
        for( j = i*MAX_GIOCATORI; j < (MAX_GIOCATORI*(i+1)); j++ ){
            int x = 0;
            if (arsqua[i].matricola == arcalc[j].matricola_squadra){
                arsqua[i].giocatori_squadra[x] = arcalc[j];
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

recap, an array of 20 player (x couter (0 to 19)), that put 20 players (j (0 to 19 - 20 to 39 etc..)) in the 20 teams (i 0 to 20), the limit is that i cant scan the whole array (400) or some errors shows up! But im good with this